# Creating relation with the values of another node instead of using that node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to store values in a relation of neo4j in Cypher Query Language?

Example: I have 3 nodes A,B,C. 'A' should relate with c using the values/properties of 'B'. Without using Node B separately we should use its values in the relation of A->C

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will create a new `FOO` relationship with the properties of the `B` node. *I made up a data model, since you did not provide yours.*

```
MATCH (a:A {name: 'a'}), (b:B {name: 'b'}), (c:C {name: 'c'})
CREATE (a)-[rel:FOO]->(c)
SET rel = b;
RETURN a, b, c, rel;
```

If you wanted to also delete the `b` node, you can add a `DELETE b` clause right before the `RETURN` (and remove `b` from the `RETURN` clause).

Comment: This is the data model i'am practicing TPCH url: ( https://github.com/alronz/b2c-database-selection/blob/master/Neo4j/Examples/TPC-H%20Queries.md ) in the url you can see in the "create model" section he had mentioned that," The Has_details relationship type is the relationship that replaces the Partsupp entity in the TPCH model and we store inside the relationship the availqty and the supplycost values that comes from the Partsupp entity." I stuck near creating this relation between(Lineitem,parts and supplier). Note i' am creating this relations entirely in Cypher not with java...